# Changed terminal permissions

Tags: osx

For no known reason I suddenly have to execute most terminal commands using sudo. For example, I have always been able to run "git pull/push" etc. without any trouble. Now, I get "permission denied". Is there any way of resetting the permissions to default? I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the first answer you have run various commands with the elevated command, `sudo`, in your personal space.  Now you have directories in your personal space that are owned, not by you, but by root.  If you type `cd` with no parameters you'll be taken to the bottom of your personal space (where it starts) and be able to see it with the `pwd` command.

On many system by default your personal space will be /home/[your username].

You can fix this `have to execute most terminal commands using sudo` by recovering access to your whole home directory.

Do this by first going to your home directory, then back out a level with `cd ..`.

Now execute this command:

```
$ sudo chown -R [your username] [your username]
```

If your username is ljames you can do this with this sequence:

```
$ cd ~ljames
$ cd ..
$ sudo chown -R ljames ljames
```

There are a number of ways to do this.  I went thought those details to help you to see where the changes are taking place.  You can effectively do this in one command line with:

```
$ sudo chown -R ljames ~ljames
```

Now when you are working in your own personal space you shouldn't get the `permission denied` errors.  You should only be denied permission when you're working outside your personal area in what is called `system wide`.  You'll have to use the elevated command `sudo` to make changes in those areas.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem! Any ideas how the permissions could have been changed in the first place? Seems a bit scary...

Comment: Yes.  It's the first line of my answer.  I'll elaborate more if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the permissions of the folders/files you are trying to modify and not on the commands themselves. You probably ran a git command as `sudo` once and that changed the ownership to root. I could give you a more specific answer if you posted the output of `ls -l` on your `git` repository.

Assuming the problem is what I described above, you can fix it by changing the ownership back to your user (replace `UserFoo` with your actual user name):

```
chown -R UserFoo /path/to/git/folder
```

Comment: Ok, here's the output:

`drwxr-xr-x  5 root  staff     170 20 Okt 13:07 data
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Erik  staff      21 17 Okt 14:26 hello.m
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff    2282 24 Okt 15:37 hello.py
-rw-r--r--  1 Erik  staff      24 17 Okt 15:25 import csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff    4619 24 Okt 15:33 result.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Erik  staff  117234  8 Okt 11:13 testing.csv`

However, this is not exclusive to git. I have the same problem with most commands which used to work previously.

Comment: @user89161 please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. That said, the issue is indeed what I suspected and my answer should solve it. Note the `root` in the output, that means that the files belong to root and you don't have access to them. The command I gave will change the ownership back to your user.